# Why do I get a memory error using .next()?

Tags: python, file-handling, memory-management

I'm trying to parse a text file in python 2.7.  The file has has around 10^11 lines so I can't load it into memory.

This works just fine:

```
with open('file_name.txt') as f:
     for row in f:
          #Do something...
```

However, I don't always want to run the script on the entire file.  I've found that this also works:

```
max_rows = 10**2
with open('file_name.txt') as f:
     for n in range(max_rows):
         row = f.next()
         #Do something...
```

However, if I set:

```
max_rows = 10**9
```

I get a memory error.  Hoping to get some insight as to why this happens, its very counter-intuitive to me.  Both scripts approaches seem like they should be reading only one line of text into memory at a time.

Comment: `range` returns a list in Python2, which takes up quite a lot of memory if you initialize with a billion elements. You probably want to use `xrange` instead. That being said, there's no reason to use your second version. Always use the first, and if you also need an index, then do `for i, row in enumerate(f)`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, very clear!